# Why do I need to cast an object to the ICryptoTransform interface to use the method TransformFinalBlock

Tags: c#, encryption

Why do I need to cast an object to the `ICryptoTransform` interface to use the method `TransformFinalBlock`

Interfaces are only method signatures according to the MSDN, but it looks like casting an object to a interface gives it not only new methods, but new functionality. How does this work?

```
using (DESCryptoServiceProvider encrypter = new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor())
{
    DES.Key = key;
    DES.GenerateIV(); // equivilant to a salt for a hash
    byte[] newCipherBytes = ((ICryptoTransform) DES).TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
}
```

The DES object implements the ICryptoTransform interface according to the intellisense, which means it HAS TO have implemented the method TransformFinalBlock.

This is not true though, this method is not accessible from the DES object.

Here is a working example i wrote to illustrate basic usage of a class with an implemented interface:

```
class Program
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This public interface enforces a method declaration on human, because human implements the interface
    /// </summary>
    public interface iBirthday
    {
        DateTime getBirthday();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Human implements the interface and the method getBirthday
    /// </summary>
    public class Human : iBirthday
    {
        private DateTime birthday = default(DateTime);
        private string name = String.Empty;

        public Human(string name, DateTime birthday)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthday = birthday;
        }

        public string getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public DateTime getBirthday()
        {
            return this.birthday;
        }

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Human james = new Human("James Brown", new DateTime(1933, 5, 3));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}'s birthday is on {1}", james.getName(),james.getBirthday());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that cast? It does not work without?

Comment: @Evk yes it requires me to cast to use the method of the interface, or at least thats how intellisense is portraying it